# System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException on empty string param

Tags: c#, sql

In my query is this line

```
//query...
"AND (@4 = '' OR (p.FirstName + p.LastName LIKE '%' + @4 + '%') OR (eup.FirstName + eup.LastName LIKE '%' + @4 + '%')) " +
//more query...
```

This is giving me a `Data is null` exception.  Param `@4` is coming in as `""`.  When I changed this to

```
"AND (@4 IS NULL OR (p.FirstName + p.LastName LIKE '%' + @4 + '%') OR (eup.FirstName + eup.LastName LIKE '%' + @4 + '%')) " +
```

It is not returning records that don't have a firstname or lastname in either table.

How can I address this?  If param 4 is empty I want to return all records regardless of the name existing or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless paramenter `@4` includes both the first and lastname with no spaces or anything I suspect you are looking for any of the first or last names that match `@4` and if `@4` is empty then to return everything.

```
AND (p.FirstName LIKE '%' ISNULL(@4,'') + '%'
    OR p.LastName LIKE '%' ISNULL(@4,'') + '%'
    OR eup.FirstName LIKE '%' ISNULL(@4,'') + '%'
    OR eup.LastName LIKE '%' ISNULL(@4,'') + '%'
    )
```

By using `ISNULL(@4,'')` it will essentially turn your first and last name into a complete wildcard search and return everything because it will still have the '%' before and after.  I might suggest altering that to just have the '%' after as you will probably get results that are more intended for a people look up but that is up to you.

The main issue with `p.FirstName + p.LastName LIKE` is that `Bob Smith` will become `BOBSMITH LIKE`.... though I suppose if you stick with the `% search string %` it will still return your results in that cause just switch you `@4` to `ISNULL(@4,'')` and get rid of the first `@4 = ''`

Comment: paramater `@4` was a concatenated first name and last name.  I am going to refactor this query completely, I don't like anything about it.

Comment: @USER_8675309 I just saw your other comment above.  If you are really looking for a solution to search an employee dataset vs your AD records, I bet there are a few questions out their on that which might get you what you want.  If not I would put that in the question itself as it is good information for people to know when providing answers to you.

Comment: Indeed.  I think there are two separate questions here, one about SQL `''` vs `null` and the other about AD users.  Our solution moving forward is to create person records for the AD users moving forward, and use a script to back-fill the existing AD users into the person table.  Thanks a bunch for your help though.  I ended up using a blend between your and phils answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that your comment "don't have a firstname or lastname in either table" suggests that the fields are nullable.
Doing any operation like p.FirstName + p.Lastname will give a null result if either value is null which in turn will cause the predicate to result in false.
Also, I personally would not concatinate the two fields at any time because your LIKE predicate can match on characters at end of the firstname and the start of the lastnmame.

Ideally you shound have the fields set to NOT NULL and then do this..

```
"AND (@4 IS NULL 
  OR p.FirstName LIKE '%' + @4 +'%' 
  OR p.LastName LIKE '%' + @4 + '%'
  OR eup.FirstName LIKE '%' + @4 +'%'
  OR eup.LastName LIKE '%' + @4 + '%')) " +
```

If the fields must remain nullable do this..

```
"AND (@4 IS NULL 
  OR coalesce(p.FirstName,'') LIKE '%' + @4 +'%' 
  OR coalesce(p.LastName,'') LIKE '%' + @4 + '%'
  OR coalesce(eup.FirstName,'') LIKE '%' + @4 +'%'
  OR coalesce(eup.LastName,'') LIKE '%' + @4 + '%')) " +
```

Neither of these - or your version - will benefit from indexing on the fields so on large tables the performance can be nasty.

Comment: The fields are not null.  The issue here is AD users are stored in a place I can't access them in this query, so there is the potential that a user exists with no corresponding person record.  It's stupid, I know, but the scope of work doesn't involve any refactoring.